# Positioning relative to a specific tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the below JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kartik987/u34xsk5e/3/

If I hover over, the image tag the "HOVER TEXT" should appear below the image, currently it appears below the "RANDOM TEXT COMING FROM API".
The "RANDOM TEXT COMING FROM API" could be a few words or even a few sentences.

I am trying to find a way to always position the "HOVER TEXT" it below the image tag.
What I have been trying is:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #fff, #e4e5f0); */
}

.tooltip {
  transform: none;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-scroll {
  display: inline;
}

.tooltip:hover>.tooltip-text,
.tooltip:hover>.wrapper {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.tooltip>.tooltip-text,
.tooltip>.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6000;
  max-width: 350px;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #575757;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  /* background: #DCDCDC; */
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #fff, #e4e5f0);
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}


/* Arrow */

.tooltip>.tooltip-text:before,
.tooltip>.wrapper:before {
  display: inline-block;
  top: -7px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) transparent;
  border-width: 0 .5em .5em .5em;
  z-index: 6000;
  /* left: calc(var(--variable-width) + 20px);*/
  /* left: 100%-20px
        
         */
  /* left: 20px; */
}


/* Invisible area so you can hover over tooltip */

.tooltip>.tooltip-text:after,
.tooltip>.wrapper:after {
  top: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  left: 20px;
}

.wrapper>.tooltip-text {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
RANDOM TEXT COMING FROM API
<span class="tooltip tooltip-scroll">
    <img style="width: 16px; height: 16px" id="di_1230575183658::::16" alt="Er" src="imag.png">
  <span class="wrapper"> 
     <span class="tooltip-text">
         HOVER TEXT
      </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

I don't want to give a move the hover span by giving a left property in px. As the "RANDOM TEXT COMING FROM API" could be a few words or even a few sentences.
Is there a way to calculate the and set the left value so that it always aligns below the image?

Comment: Your last sentence could use some editing to make your intent more clearly stated and improve grammar re: "I don't want to give a move the hover span"

Comment: FWIW this looks like way too much CSS for what I currently view as your intent here.

Comment: note `.tooltip:hover>.tooltip-text,` is not valid/useful since the text is not a direct descendent of the tooltip

Answer (score 0):

You want to know that `position: relative`  does not create a stacking context on inline elements. So your `.tooltip` should be e.g. `inline-block`:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #fff, #e4e5f0); */
}

.tooltip {
  transform: none;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-scroll {
}

.tooltip:hover>.tooltip-text,
.tooltip:hover>.wrapper {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.tooltip>.tooltip-text,
.tooltip>.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6000;
  max-width: 350px;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #575757;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  /* background: #DCDCDC; */
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #fff, #e4e5f0);
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}


/* Arrow */

.tooltip>.tooltip-text:before,
.tooltip>.wrapper:before {
  display: inline-block;
  top: -7px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) transparent;
  border-width: 0 .5em .5em .5em;
  z-index: 6000;
  /* left: calc(var(--variable-width) + 20px);*/
  /* left: 100%-20px
        
         */
  /* left: 20px; */
}

.tooltip>.wrapper {position:absolute}
/* Invisible area so you can hover over tooltip */

.tooltip>.tooltip-text:after,
.tooltip>.wrapper:after {
  top: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  left: 20px;
}

.wrapper>.tooltip-text {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
RANDOM TEXT COMING FROM API
<span class="tooltip tooltip-scroll">
    <img style="width: 16px; height: 16px" id="di_1230575183658::::16" alt="Er" src="imag.png">
  <span class="wrapper"> 
     <span class="tooltip-text">
         HOVER TEXT
      </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

- `.tooltip>.tooltip-text,` removed these as invalid selector
- Left comment on CSS that was not needed.

Most of this is fairly self explained by the CSS perhaps. the key is the various `transform` such as `transform: translate(-1em, 7em);`

- I did add a wrapper to make positioning easier relative due to that
- use `em` as my brain works better with that so `1em` == `16px` etc.
- note how the "arrow" centers under the image and the alt text kind of messes with the size as it is wider than the 1X1 em/16px

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ff00ff;
}

.tooltip-container {
  /* this becomes the hover area */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin-top: -6em;
  padding: 1.5em;
  border: solid 1px #FF0000;
  transform: translate(-1em, 7em);
}

.tooltip {
   border: solid 1px #00FF00;
}

.wrapper {
  transform: translate(-1em, -0.25em);
}

/* span has this already
.tooltip-scroll {
  display: inline;
}
*/

.tooltip>.wrapper {
  display: block;
  z-index: 6000;
  max-width: 21.875em;
  min-width: 10em;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #575757;
  margin-top: 0.625em;
  line-height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  color: black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #fff, #e4e5f0);
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.tooltip-container:hover>.tooltip>.wrapper {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.tooltip>.wrapper:before {
  /* Arrow */
  display: block;
  transform: translate(0.5em, -0.75em);
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) transparent;
  border-width: 0 .5em .5em .5em;
  z-index: 6000;
}
```

```html
RANDOM TEXT COMING FROM API
<span class="tooltip-container">
  <span class="tooltip tooltip-scroll">
      <img id="di_1230575183658::::16" alt="Er" src="imag.png" />
    <span class="wrapper"><span class="tooltip-text">HOVER TEXT this is better bigger perhaps for our test and even better with more </span></span>
</span>
</span>/*.tooltip>.tooltip-text,  invalid selector */
```

Comment: I added some ugly borders just to show what was where but not needed otherwise.